# Parsing emails in Outlook using C# via POP3 server

Tags: c#, cdo.message

So I am trying to get certain data out of emails I'm receiving at work, so that I can take the wanted data and put into an excel document (probably going to need to ask questions about this later). So far, I have successfully read through my entire email inbox, and found the emails that I want from a specific address. My program, as of right now, saves those emails into a folder as .eml files.

Now, my question is how do I read in the body of the emails so that I can parse what I need from them?

My first attempt(s) are using Microsoft CDO. I am trying to call a method that I have pieced together from researching online, but can't seem to get it to work. Visual Studio is telling me 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'receivemail.Program.ReadMessage(string)'

Any help would be awesome, and I can answer any more questions if this is too broad or anyone needs more specifics. I'll paste my code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;

// Add EAGetMail namespace
using EAGetMail;

// Add CDO
using CDO.Message;

namespace receiveemail
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a folder named "inbox" under current directory
            // to save the email retrieved.
            string curpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string mailbox = String.Format("{0}\\WorkOrders", curpath);

            // If the folder is not existed, create it.
            if (!Directory.Exists(mailbox))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(mailbox);
            }

            MailServer oServer = new MailServer("pop-mail.outlook.com",
                        "email@email.com", "pass", ServerProtocol.Pop3);

            MailClient oClient = new MailClient("TryIt");

            //POP3 SSL connection
            oServer.SSLConnection = true;
            oServer.Port = 995;

            try
            {
                oClient.Connect(oServer);
                MailInfo[] infos = oClient.GetMailInfos();
                for (int i = 0; i < infos.Length; i++)
                {
                    MailInfo info = infos[i];
                    Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}; Size: {1}; UIDL: {2}",
                        info.Index, info.Size, info.UIDL);

                    // Receive email from POP3 server
                    Mail oMail = oClient.GetMail(info);
                    if (oMail.From.ToString() == "johndoe@yahoo.com")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("From: {0}", oMail.From.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}\r\n", oMail.Subject);

                        // Generate an email file name based on date time.
                        System.DateTime d = System.DateTime.Now;
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo cur = new
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
                        string sdate = d.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss", cur);
                        string fileName = String.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}{3}.eml",
                        mailbox, sdate, d.Millisecond.ToString("d3"), i);

                        // Save email                   
                        oMail.SaveAs(fileName, true);
                        CDO.Message msg = ReadMessage(fileName);
                        Console.WriteLine(msg.TextBody);
                    } // end if

                    // Mark email as deleted from POP3 server.
                    oClient.Delete(info);
                }
                // Quit and purge emails marked as deleted from POP3 server.
                // oClient.Quit();

            } catch (Exception ep)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
            } // end catch

        } // end method

        protected CDO.Message ReadMessage(String emlFileName)
        {
            CDO.Message msg = new CDO.MessageClass();
            ADODB.Stream stream = new ADODB.StreamClass();
            stream.Open(Type.Missing, ADODB.ConnectModeEnum.adModeUnknown, ADODB.StreamOpenOptionsEnum.adOpenStreamUnspecified, String.Empty, String.Empty);
            stream.LoadFromFile(emlFileName);
            stream.Flush();
            msg.DataSource.OpenObject(stream, "_Stream");
            msg.DataSource.Save();
            return msg;
        }

    } // end class

} // end namespace
```

Note that those aren't the *real* email addresses and passwords ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The ReadMessage method is not static, and you're trying to call it from the static Main method. So either make ReadMessage static or create an instance of the Program class and then call ReadMessage on that.

Comment: The way you worded that makes me feel dumb. I should've known that from my java experience.